# Can tr work with regex?

Tags: linux, regular-expression, tr

I have a file like this:

```
AAAA  
BBBB  
CCCC   
DDDD   
etc
```

Words in separate lines. I want to add them quotes using `tr`.
So I tried the following:

1) To add a quote in the start of each word i.e. `'AAAA`

- `tr '^\w$' '\'\w$' <file.txt`  Does not work
- `tr '^\w$' ''\w$' <file.txt`  Does not work

Both of the above make the command line stuck.

2) To add quote to the end I tried:

`tr '\n' ''\n' <file.txt`  But this does not work and the command line gets stuck.

Why don't these regex work with `tr`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't replace multiple things like this with `tr`. I would use `sed` to do this instead.

#### Example

```
$ sed "s/^/'/" file.txt
'AAAA
'BBBB
'CCCC
'DDDD
```

Says to find the beginning of each line (`^`) and replace it with a single quote (`'`).

If you want to wrap the "words" in single quotes you can use this form of the command:

```
$ sed "s/\(.*\)/'\1'/" file.txt
'AAAA'
'BBBB'
'CCCC'
'DDDD'
```

This time we're saving anything on the line in a temporary variable (`\1`). We then replace the line with this `'\1'`.

This command can be abbreviated to this, use GNU specific switches:

```
$ sed -r "s/^(.*)$/'&'/" file.txt
'AAAA'
'BBBB'
'CCCC'
'DDDD'
```

Comment: For adding the ending quote too, I'll modify it to `sed -r "s/^(.*)$/'&'/" file.txt`.

Comment: `-r` is GNU specific. `sed "s/.*/'&'/"`. No need for ^ or $ or to capture the whole pattern.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - thanks I've mentioned that in my answer (GNU) and removed the redundant anchor characters.

Answer (score 5):

`tr` is for transliteration. One popular use of `tr` is change the case of strings:

```
$ echo 'this is a test' | tr a-z A-Z
THIS IS A TEST
```

Some operating systems version of `tr`, need the `a-z` to be of the form `[a-z]`, in which case it should also be quote:

```
$ echo 'this is a test' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
THIS IS A TEST
```

Info you have the `info` package installed on your system, the tr page has some very good examples and further explanation of the `tr` command:

`info coreutils 'tr invocation'`

For what you are trying to achieve you probably want to use sed, perl or awk.

Perl:

```
perl -pe "s/^/'/" file
```

for each line, Match the start of the line (`^`), replace with `'`

Sed:

```
sed "s/^/'/" file
```

Similar to the perl example

Awk:

```
awk -v x="'" '{ print x$0 }' foo
```

Assign the variable x to be `'` and for each line print `'` and then the whole line

Answer (score 3):

No, `tr` is only for substituting characters one by one. You cannot add characters this way.

You can use something like perl to do so:

```
perl -pe "s/\w+/'$&'/"
```

---

With `tr` you can only for example substitute one kind of quote by another kind:

```
tr \" \'
```

Those backslashes are only to tell your shell to send the character as it is and not trying to interpret it itself.

Those will not work:

```
tr '"' '''
tr '"' '\''
```

The first argument (`'"'`) is fine it is exactly the same than `\"`.
The second argument in both cases does not work: you cannot quote single quotes using single quotes as the second quote ends the quoting and the third quote opens a new one which is missing. (therefore your shell opens a new line to wait for the missing end quote.)

But all of this is just shell stuff und has nothing to do with `tr`.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest solution is generally using the simplest one-task utility.

`tr` is a simple utility, but for something else: transliteration (turning given characters  into other ones), removing given characters or squeezing characters.

More generic utilities like `sed`, `awk` or `perl` (by order of size) will do it, but here, you've got a one-task utility that would do it well as well: `paste`:

```
paste -d\' /dev/null file.txt /dev/null
```

Or:

```
:|paste -d\' - file.txt -
```